# How do I add the Linux kernel version to a Grafana dashboard using Graphite?

Tags: grafana, graphite, statsd, collectd

I was looking into the possibility of displaying a kernel version to the grafana dashboard. Has anyone had any luck sending this information to the dashboard?

I am thinking that it would be stored as a singlestat dash, and am trying to determine the best method for displaying this type of information. Would I have to sent the kernel version over statsD, or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Graphite isn't really well-suited to storing something like the kernel version, since it isn't a number.

Comment: Would you have any recommendations on other data sources that could provide these type of details?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using InfluxDB as the Datasource, using `last()` on your value will help display string data.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not using InfluxDB as datasource at this time, but will consider adding it in the near future. For now, I am going to see if the HTML markup in the text panels support REST APIs, and might grab it from there if that works.

Comment: Did your post specify Graphite before? If so, my apologies. Influx is also not the best suited for string data in fields, but with the right plugins it does alright. When I was getting started with trying to use strings in my grafana dashboards, I found the singlestat panel quite useful.